# syzygy tablebase generation program

Tags: engines

I am a linux user and have been able to write not-too-complex C programs.  I have also used makefiles. I have tried to download tablebase generator programs from GitHub but do not understand how to do this. The site seems to be primarily for programmers rather than users. I'm also not sure whether downloading source code costs money there.

Comment: syzygy is a highly complicated compression scheme. If you don't know much, you probably shouldn't bother.

Comment: The source code is free. https://github.com/syzygy1/tb An overview is given on how to build/run the TB generator program. No knowledge of its compression scheme is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, everything on Github can be downloaded freely.  Normally, there should be a download button somewhere.  Do you have a specific project in mind sou want to download?  There seem to be several tablebase generators available.  One is available from https://github.com/syzygy1/tb it seems to have decent documentation.  There is a green button on the top right labeled "Clone or download", which allows you to download the whole thing as a zip file.  From there you will have to follow the provided instructions to compile it.  For questions on this another, more programming-related SE, may be more appropriate.

Comment: Can everything on Github be downloaded freely? When you speak of open source, this is probably almost true; but it is not true of Github content in general as far as I know.

Comment: @thb Everything on Github can be download for free. Whether it's free to use in your own project (like commercial) is a different story.